# compiling android kernel for Ok6410 board

Tags: android, compilation, embedded, kernel

The Ok6410 board comes with android 2.3 source code (including the kernel), I want to customize the kernel and then use  it but during the compilation I am getting strange errors, I got the [Ok6410 board](http://arm9board.net/sel/prddetail.aspx?id=348&pid=200) from my friend now the problem is that (the official support is in Chinese), I followed the compilation process as written in the documentation (I translated the documentation by the google translate) but still I get some errors, I am using Ubuntu 11.04.
Here are the steps I followed (and they are exactly the same as written in manual, I am re-writing it so that no one needs to see the documentation).

Make a folder android in the desktop.

1. cd Desktop/android
2. sudo su
3. tar jxvf arm-none-linux-gnueabi-arm-2008q3-72-for-linux.tar.bz2 -C /
4. tar zxvf arm-linux-gcc-4.3.2.tgz -C /
5. ls /usr/local/arm/ -l

[
The output of the above command is the same as written in manual:

root@ubuntu:/home/usama/Desktop/android# ls /usr/local/arm/ -l

total 8

```
drwxr-xr-x 7 root  root  4096 2009-03-25 12:08 4.3.2 
drwxr-xr-x 8 usama usama 4096 2009-02-25 15:30 arm-none-linux-gnueabi
```

]

6 tar zxvf android_boot-android2.3-128M.tar.gz

7 cd android_boot-android2.3-128M

There was a problem in the MakeFile, the path of CROSS_COMPILE was wrong, it was previously

```
CROSS_COMPILE = / usr/local/arm/4.2.2-eabi/usr/bin/arm-linux-
```

This was wrong, I changed it to

```
CROSS_COMPILE = / usr/local/arm/4.3.2/bin/arm-linux-
```

[when the path was not changed, I received the errors,

```
make: /usr/local/arm/4.2.2-eabi/usr/bin/arm-linux-gcc: Command not found
```

changing the path removes this error,

```
root@ubuntu:/home/usama/Desktop/android/android_boot-android2.3-128M# gedit Makefile 

(gedit:6888): Gtk-WARNING **: Attempting to store changes into `/root/.local/share/recently-used.xbel', but failed: Failed to create file '/root/.local/share/recently-used.xbel.X6LD9V': No such file or directory 
(gedit:6888): Gtk-WARNING **: Attempting to set the permissions of `/root/.local/share/recently-used.xbel', but failed: No such file or directory 
(gedit:6888): Gtk-WARNING **: Attempting to store changes into `/root/.local/share/recently-used.xbel', but failed: Failed to create file '/root/.local/share/recently-used.xbel.MT0E9V': No such file or directory 
(gedit:6888): Gtk-WARNING **: Attempting to set the permissions of `/root/.local/share/recently-used.xbel', but failed: No such file or directory 
(gedit:6888): Gtk-WARNING **: Attempting to store changes into `/root/.local/share/recently-used.xbel', but failed: Failed to create file '/root/.local/share/recently-used.xbel.MFVT9V': No such file or directory 
(gedit:6888): Gtk-WARNING **: Attempting to set the permissions of `/root/.local/share/recently-used.xbel', but failed: No such file or directory
```

]

[make clean is recommended after changing path in the MakeFile, but it results in the errors shown below]

8 make clean

```
root@ubuntu:/home/usama/Desktop/android/android_boot-android2.3-128M# make clean
make: execvp: /: Permission denied 
find /home/usama/Desktop/android/android_boot-android2.3-128M -type f \ 
    \( -name 'core' -o -name '*.bak' -o -name '*~' \ 
    -o -name '*~' -o -name '.depend*' \ 
    -o -name '*.o'  -o -name '*.a'  \) -print \ 
    | xargs rm -f 
rm -f u-boot* 
rm -f examples/hello_world examples/timer \ 
      examples/eepro100_eeprom examples/sched \ 
      examples/mem_to_mem_idma2intr examples/82559_eeprom \ 
      examples/smc91111_eeprom examples/interrupt \ 
      examples/test_burst 
rm -f tools/img2srec tools/mkimage tools/envcrc \ 
    tools/gen_eth_addr 
rm -f tools/mpc86x_clk tools/ncb 
rm -f tools/easylogo/easylogo tools/bmp_logo 
rm -f tools/gdb/astest tools/gdb/gdbcont tools/gdb/gdbsend 
rm -f tools/env/fw_printenv tools/env/fw_setenv 
rm -f board/cray/L1/bootscript.c board/cray/L1/bootscript.image 
rm -f board/netstar/eeprom board/netstar/crcek board/netstar/crcit 
rm -f board/netstar/*.srec board/netstar/*.bin 
rm -f board/trab/trab_fkt board/voiceblue/eeprom 
rm -f board/integratorap/u-boot.lds board/integratorcp/u-boot.lds 
rm -f include/bmp_logo.h 
rm -f nand_spl/u-boot-spl nand_spl/u-boot-spl.map
```

Note: execvp seems to be some source of error, but I don't know what it is.

9 export PATH=/usr/local/arm/4.3.2/bin/:$PATH

10 make

```
root@ubuntu:/home/usama/Desktop/android/android_boot-android2.3-128M# make 
make: execvp: /: Permission denied 
for dir in tools examples post post/cpu ; do make -C $dir _depend ; done 
make[1]: execvp: /: Permission denied 
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/usama/Desktop/android/android_boot-android2.3-128M/tools' 
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/usama/Desktop/android/android_boot-android2.3-128M/tools' 
make[1]: execvp: /: Permission denied 
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/usama/Desktop/android/android_boot-android2.3-128M/tools' 
make[1]: Nothing to be done for `_depend'. 
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/usama/Desktop/android/android_boot-android2.3-128M/tools' 
make[1]: execvp: /: Permission denied 
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/usama/Desktop/android/android_boot-android2.3-128M/examples' 
/bin/sh: /: Permission denied 
dirname: missing operand 
Try `dirname --help' for more information. 
/bin/sh: /: Permission denied 
dirname: missing operand 
Try `dirname --help' for more information. 
/bin/sh: /: Permission denied 
/bin/sh: /: Permission denied 
 make[1]: *** No rule to make target `.depend', needed by `_depend'.  Stop. 
 make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/usama/Desktop/android/android_boot-android2.3-128M/examples' 
 make[1]: execvp: /: Permission denied 
 make[1]: Entering directory `/home/usama/Desktop/android/android_boot-android2.3-128M/post' 
/bin/sh: /: Permission denied 
/bin/sh: /: Permission denied 
/bin/sh: /: Permission denied 
/bin/sh: /: Permission denied 
/bin/sh: /: Permission denied 
/bin/sh: /: Permission denied 
/bin/sh: /: Permission denied 
/bin/sh: /: Permission denied 
/bin/sh: /: Permission denied 
/bin/sh: /: Permission denied 
/bin/sh: /: Permission denied 
/bin/sh: /: Permission denied 
/bin/sh: /: Permission denied 
/bin/sh: /: Permission denied 
/bin/sh: /: Permission denied 
/bin/sh: /: Permission denied 
make[1]: *** No rule to make target `.depend', needed by `_depend'.  Stop. 
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/usama/Desktop/android/android_boot-android2.3-128M/post' 
make[1]: execvp: /: Permission denied 
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/usama/Desktop/android/android_boot-android2.3-128M/post/cpu' 
/bin/sh: /: Permission denied 
/bin/sh: /: Permission denied 
/bin/sh: /: Permission denied 
/bin/sh: /: Permission denied 
/bin/sh: /: Permission denied 
/bin/sh: /: Permission denied 
/bin/sh: /: Permission denied 
/bin/sh: /: Permission denied 
/bin/sh: /: Permission denied 
/bin/sh: /: Permission denied 
/bin/sh: /: Permission denied 
/bin/sh: /: Permission denied 
/bin/sh: /: Permission denied 
/bin/sh: /: Permission denied 
/bin/sh: /: Permission denied 
/bin/sh: /: Permission denied 
/bin/sh: /: Permission denied 
/bin/sh: /: Permission denied 
/bin/sh: /: Permission denied 
/bin/sh: /: Permission denied 
make[1]: *** No rule to make target `.depend', needed by `_depend'.  Stop. 
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/usama/Desktop/android/android_boot-android2.3-128M   /post/cpu' 
make: *** [depend] Error 2
```

Now if anyone can tell that what is the problem and how it can be resolved:

I tried to ask this question in the forums of [witech](http://bbs.witech.com.cn/) (the company which sales this board) but I m not even able to make account in those forums as all those (registration etc)instructions are in Chinese and Google Translate doesn't work much better.

I know many of u may not have tried android on Ok6410, but anyone who has expertise in Linux and android compilation can find out the problem.

**Note:**

This is happening in the very initial step of kernel compilation, all these errors come while compiling uboot, actual kernel source compilation haven't started yet.

Thanks for the help.

regards

usama

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this command:

```
make smdk6410_config
```

before giving the make command. I think it may work.